# Invalid Stream Header - Socket Transfer in Java

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, deserialization

I have another problem.

This is a part of my client:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutput oo = null;
            try {
              oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
              oo.writeObject(mp3dataStrings);
              byte[] serializedMP3 = bos.toByteArray();
              out.write(serializedMP3);
                out.flush();
            } finally {
              oo.close();
              bos.close();
            }
```

this is a part of my server:

```
ServerSocket clientConnect = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("SimpleServer running on port" + port);
        Socket clientSock = clientConnect.accept();
        InputStream is = clientSock.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
          int b = is.read();
          buffer[i] = (byte) b;
          if (b == -1 | b == 0) break;
        }
        ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
        String[][] songs = (String[][]) stream.readObject();
        stream.close();
```

When I send my object (a String[][]) I get the exception invalid stream header: ACED0000.

I can't find what this means and what I have to do.

greets
Alex

Comment: Why did you copy the input stream to a buffer, then pass this buffer to a ByteArrayInputStream ?

Comment: @benjarobin why would that be a problem? Sounds like a hint to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made it far more complicated than you need to.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);
try {
  ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());   
  oo.writeObject(mp3dataStrings);
  oo.close();
} finally {
  socket.close();
}
```

and

```
ServerSocket clientConnect = new ServerSocket(port);
System.out.println("SimpleServer running on port" + port);

Socket clientSock = clientConnect.accept();
try {
  ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());
  String[][] songs = (String[][]) stream.readObject();
} finally {
  clientSock.close();
}
```

Comment: I am using this solution and I have an error in the server. I got invalid stream header socket if the server is not my computer. Any clue?

Comment: @FranzéJr. Most likely the server is not writing an object output stream. What wire protocol is the server using?

Comment: It's working now. Probably some "clean" problem. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter Lawrey's answer, however the problem in your original code stems from the exit condition in the byte buffer population code

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
      int b = is.read();
      // THIS ARE PROBLEM LINES
      buffer[i] = (byte) b;
      if (b == -1 | b == 0) break;
    }
    ObjectInputStream stream = 
      new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
```

You should only exit this loop when you've detected End-Of-Stream condition. In other words you should never consider `b==0`, as it is a valid part of the ObjectInputStream.

Second, you should not assign the byte to the buffer before checking for break condition.

Third, if you initialize ByteArrayInputStream, you should pass only the number of bytes that contain input, not the whole buffer itself.

Corrected block should be like this:

```
// How do you know if 1024 is enough to get all data?
// For the sake of this example, assume it's enough
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int count = 0;
for (; count < buffer.length; count++) {
  int b = is.read();

  if ( b == -1 )
  {
    // exit only on End-Of-Stream, and do not record
    // this result into the buffer
    break;
  }

  buffer[count] = (byte) b;
}

ObjectInputStream stream = 
  new ObjectInputStream( 
    // Note, that we are now passing the number of 'active' bytes in the buffer
    new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer, 0, count)
  );
```

Comment: thank you very much! I will apply it in the future. happy new year